# Capturing the login failed event in Symfony3

Tags: json, redirect, symfony

I have this set up in `security.yml`;

```
 failure_path:      /login
```

This redirects a user to the log in page if they are not authenticated when trying to access specific URLs set in `access_control` e.g.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But I cannot seem to capture this redirect.

I have tried to use a service for the `security.authentication.failure` event but this does not work

```
app.security.authentication_failure_event_listener:
    class: MemberBundle\Event\AuthenticationListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.failure, method: onAuthenticationFailure }
```

The redirect still occurs and the `onAuthenticationFailure` is never called. Presumably because authentication has not explicitly failed. The user just isn't logged in and is redirected.

The reason is because I want to give different response based on the expected format. For example I want html requests to go to the login page, but JSON requests should return valid JSON - and not the HTML login form page.

I feel like the FOSRestBundle may handle this, but it seems overkill for this relatively simple need. And its not a RESTFul web site so I shouldn't need that bundle to do this?

I also tried a service to listen for Exceptions but this did not work either. I guess the redirect that occurs doesn't throw an Exception?

```
app.exception_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

So how can I always capture the redirect event that occurs when `failure_path` is set in `security.yml`?

Comment: Can you give me some feedback about my answer?

Comment: @gp_sflover not yet, I haven't used it yet and your final suggestion I have already tried as stated in my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this lay in a subtle thing about Symfony and the AccessDeniedException.

In that the Exception is only thrown based on your access controls if the current user is not allowed access. It is not thrown if you are not authenticated at all.

The same is true for any sort of authentication failure hook. Its only called with some sort of auth fails, not if you're simply not logged in and therefore not allowed.

So its done via two new services

```
app.exception_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }

app.entry_point:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\EntryPoint
    arguments: ["@router"]
```

The first does capture the AccessDeniedException as you would expect when you're denied access to a resource.

```
class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        do {
            if ($exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                $request = $event->getRequest();
                if ('json' == $request->get("format") || $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                    $json = new JsonResponse(["status" => 0, 'not_logged_in' => true, "msg" => "You must be logged in"]);
                    $event->setResponse($json);
                }
            }
        } while (null !== $exception = $exception->getPrevious());
    }
}
```

The entry point service needs to be set in `security.yml` like to

```
security
    firewalls:
        main:
            entry_point: app.entry_point
```

This class handles the start of the firewall and handles the redirection to authenticate. I check for the Exception is present and then test for XHR and json format and handle accordingly.

```
/**
 * Returns a response that directs the user to authenticate.
 *
 * This is called when an anonymous request accesses a resource that
 * requires authentication. The job of this method is to return some
 * response that "helps" the user start into the authentication process.
 *
 * Examples:
 *  A) For a form login, you might redirect to the login page
 *      return new RedirectResponse('/login');
 *  B) For an API token authentication system, you return a 401 response
 *      return new Response('Auth header required', 401);
 *
 * @param Request                 $request       The request that resulted in an AuthenticationException
 * @param AuthenticationException $authException The exception that started the authentication process
 *
 * @return Response
 */
class EntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{
    /** @var  Router */
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null) {
        if($authException) {
            if('json' == $request->get("format") || $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                return new JsonResponse(["status" => 0, 'not_logged_in' => true, "msg" => "You must be logged in"]);
            }
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate("fos_user_security_login"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Tip (also for the future) is to "[Create a Custom Authentication System with Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html). Much More simple and more flexible/customizable to handle that stuff (specially if a bit complicated with many authenticators like facebook, twitter, etc... and with a remember me option activated...).

But... as showed in the [SecurityBundle Configuration ("security")](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration) you can set a `failure_handler` parameter for each login system in that firewall:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        your_firewall_name:
             form_login:
                 failure_handler: your_custom_failure_handler_service_name <-- THIS ONE
```

Then you can create a service injecting the needed dependencies to handle the stuff you need and to return a different response based on the request format.

**NOTE**: I'm not sure if you can achieve this also creating a listener for the [Security authentication event failure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events), but you can give it a try.

Comment: It was helpful, but didn't quite get me to the answer. I have posted a new answer.